# What can I do when I'd like to increase the offering of a bounty?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

As the title says, what can I do?
May I start a new bounty of the same question?

Comment: Nope. One bounty at a time, no increases allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new bounty when the old bounty ends (given that you have enough repuation to offer a new bounty), but in your case, the new bounty **must be** greater than the original one.

A single user cannot offer the same bounty amount twice on the same question.